# Set replica set member host names on Secondary

Tags: mongodb, update

I have a replica set `rset1` that consists of a primary, secondary, and a backup server.

I recently just changed their DNS names in Route53--the only name that didn't change was the Primary's, however since it can't connect to the secondaries, it stepped-down from being Primary.

I've been trying write a query to use in an update of `local.system.replset`, where `local` is the database and `system.replset` the collection; I can't seem to get anywhere with it, though.

Here's what `system.replset` looks like:

```
{ "_id" : "rset1",
  "version" : 7,
  "members" : [
    { "_id" : 0,
      "host" : "mongo-rs1-p.foo-bar.com:27017", 
      "priority" : 3
    }, 
    { "_id" : 1,
      "host" : "mongo-rs1-s1.foo-bar.com:27017",
      "priority" : 2
    },
    { "_id" : 2,
      "host" : "mongo-rs1-s0.foo-bar.com:27017"
    }
  ] 
}
```

I need to change `members` to this:

```
 [
   { "_id": 0,
     "host": "mongo-rs-p.foo-bar.com:27017",
     "priority": 3
   },
   { "_id": 1,
     "host": "mongo-rs1-s.foo-bar.com:27017",
     "priority": 2
   },
   { "_id": 2,
     "host": "mongo-rs1-b.foo-bar.com:27017"
   }
]
```

I've tried using:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[1].host = "mongo-rs1-s.foo-bar.com:27017"
cfg.members[2].host = "mongo-rs1-b.foo-bar.com:27017"
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

But since the primary is no longer primary, I can't get this to run successfully, and running `db.getMongo().setSlaveOk()` didn't help with using `rs.reconfig()`

As a last resort (I've had this problem before) I can run `rm -rf /data; mkdir -p /data` to remove mongo's data directory (after killing the `mongod` process) and then I can start the mongod server again and rebuild the replica set from scratch, but I'd rather not do that.

So how can I update the members of the replica set without deleting the database on a primary that  stepped down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide for how to do this (reconfigure a replica set with unavailable members) here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/

You essentially have to do a [forced reconfig](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-commands/#rs.reconfig) of the set because there is no primary available.  If you want to keep a set operational while doing this type of move, you can:

1. Use your hosts file to temporarily point the old names to the new (or similar) and "fool" the primary into thinking they are up (then make the permanent changes one at a time)
2. Temporarily add arbiters to prevent the primary from stepping down (2 more for example, so the primary is kept with 3/5 votes)
3. Reconfigure the set to a single node before doing the moves
4. Do the moves one server at a time, ensuring there are 2/3 nodes up to form a majority at all times (and hence keep a primary up)